# Access file directory outside main Bundle

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a `NSArray` of strings, something like this:

OBJECT 1
OBJECT 2
OBJECT 3

Now, Inside a local folder, I have folders with the objects name:

/User/Dropbox/ALLOBJECTS

OBJECT 1
OBJECT 2
OBJECT 3

Inside each folder, I have two pictures named after the objects:

OBJECT1-PIC1.png
OBJECT1-PIC2.png

What I need is the path to those pictures, basically, My object has two columns (FILE1, FILE2) which I want to save the pictures.

I will iterate through the array, find the Folder with the same name (inside a local folder) and copy the pictures.

I'm trying to use, as a test:

```
NSString *filePath = @"~/Users/me/Dropbox/ALLOBJECTS"

NSData *data = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:filePath];

NSLog(@"data: %@", data);
```

but am getting `NULL` data.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will only work on the simulator.

```
NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray* rootContent = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:@"/Users/me/Pictures" error:nil];
NSLog (@"pictures dir contains:");
for (NSString* fileName in rootContent)
    NSLog (@"%@", fileName);

NSData *data = [fileManager contentsAtPath:@"/Users/me/Pictures/Pw0wF.png"];

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```